# Would it be legal for a minor to participate in social gambling?

Tags: united-states, texas, gambling

Someone is holding a poker game, would it be legal for a minor to participate? This is in Texas.

Comment: The question seems to assume that this is for real money stakes, although it could be more clear. It isn't illegal, in general, to play poker in Texas.

Comment: @ohwilleke If it were, there'd be some serious question as to why one of the most popular variants of the game is called "Texas Hold'em"...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Russian roulette isn't legal in Russia.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, [it would be a juvenile offense for a minor to gamble and a crime for an adult to do so](https://guides.sll.texas.gov/gambling) (assuming that the minor is old enough to be prosecuted for juvenile delinquency, you can't prosecute a two year old for playing poker).

There are affirmative defenses to this crime (and the parallel juvenile offense) if:

- the actor engaged in gambling in a private place;
- no person received any economic benefit other than personal winnings; and
- except for the advantage of skill or luck, the risks of losing and the chances of winning were the same for all participants

Comment: The affirmative defences would likely apply to most private poker games. So would they also apply in the case of minors? Your answer doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Almost every criminal offense is also a ground for a juvenile delinquency charge for an old enough minor (only a few offenses, like murder, are allowed against children just barely old enough to be charged). When a criminal offense is also a juvenile delinquency charge ground, the elements of the crime and the defenses to it are the same.